# The use of "or" in evaluating integers

Tags: python

The problem "Given 2 ints, a and b, return True if one if them is 10 or if their sum is 10."

In the first test why does entering (9,9) and (8,3) return True?

I have since solved the problem using a different solution (further below) but I am struggling to understand why the first solution does not work since neither integer is 10 nor do they equal 10 when summed together!

Thanks for your help.

```
def makes10(a, b):                                        

    if a or b == 10:
        return True

    if a + b == 10:
        return True

    else:
        return False

def makes10(a, b):

    if a == 10:
        return True

    if b == 10:
        return True

    if a + b == 10:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `a or b == 10` means `(a != 0) or (b == 10)`.  The construct you wanted is `a == 10 or b == 10`.  Is that enough for you to understand your mistake?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Ah, yes. @timgeb: that is a much better duplicate than the one I picked. Variations of this question have been asked so many times. Thanks!

Comment: So in this case "a" could be any possible number?

Comment: Aside: `return (a == 10) or (b == 10) or (a+b == 10)` may be more readable.

Comment: It was difficult to find answer to this Bryan. I did try :)

Comment: This is the proposed solution: def makes10(a, b):
  return (a == 10 or b == 10 or a+b == 10)

Answer (score 3):

It says `a or b == 10`, since a is true, i.e not zero it returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Because this:

```
if a or b == 10:
```

is executed as the equivalent of

```
temp = (a or b)
if (temp == 10):
```

YOu can **NOT** test multiple values against a single fixed value like that. You have to test each one individually, e.g. if you had

```
if (a == 10) or (b == 10):
```

the statement would have worked. Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: I think `a` evaluates to True and `b` is not evaluated.

Comment: yes. but `or` still has a higher priority than `==`, so you're testing the result of the `or` against `10`, not the individual `a` or `b` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
a or b == 10
```

This evaluates to True as `a` evaluates to True

You must write

```
(a == 10) or (b == 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if a or b == 10:
```

That doesn't do what you think it does. It will be evaluated as:

```
if (a) or (b == 10):
```

You most likely want:

```
if a == 10 or b == 10:
```

Comment: So any number other than "0" would return True if you wrote: if a: ...

Comment: @GavMac Yes. That's correct. Look up the terms "truthy" and "falsey".

Comment: Thanks Carcigenicate!

Comment: @GavMac No problem. Get lots of practice setting up conditions and understanding how truthy and falsey values work. You'll be using those concepts constantly.

Answer (score 1):

```
a or b == 10
```

This will first evaluate a in the context of a boolean expression, and if this is true the whole expression is just true. If it is false, then it will evaluate `b == 10`. It is different from `a == 10 or b == 10`.

Alternatively, you would just say

```
if 10 in [a, b]:
```

this will also do what you want to accomplish.